# Getting a strange syntantical error in db2 for sql query

Tags: sql, database, db2

I am running this query in db2:

```
with closure (obj_1, obj_2) as (SELECT distinct t.obj_1, t.obj_2 FROM temp4 t
UNION ALL SELECT c.obj_1, t.obj_2 FROM closure c, temp4 t WHERE c.obj_2=t.obj_1)
```

I keep getting this error and I'm not sure how to fix it since the unexpected token IS the expected token?:

```
SQL0104N  An unexpected token ")" was found following "HERE c.obj_2=t.obj_1".  
Expected tokens may include:  ")".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

Comment: `SELECT distinct f.obj_1, f.obj_2 FROM temp4 t` - Looks like you are using the alias `f` in your field list instead of `t`.  I would also switch to `INNER JOIN` in the second half instead of a cross-join with a filter.

Comment: @DStanley good catch! and are you suggesting this? `with closure (obj_1, obj_2) as (SELECT t.obj_1, t.obj_2 FROM temp4 t UNION ALL SELECT c.obj_1, t.obj_2 FROM closure c, temp4 t)`

Comment: No keep the union but change the second half to `SELECT c.obj_1, t.obj_2 FROM closure c INNER JOIN temp4 t ON c.obj_2=t.obj_1`

Comment: @DStanley Unfortunately, making it an inner join gives me the following error: `The fullselect of the recursive common table expression 
"XXXX.CLOSURE" must be the UNION of two or more fullselects and cannot 
include column functions, GROUP BY clause, HAVING clause, ORDER BY clause, or 
an explicit join including an ON clause.  SQLSTATE=42836`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a Common Table Expression (CTE) only - the SELECT for the CTE is missing (in addition to the comment from D Stanley.

So check out something like this:

```
with closure (obj_1, obj_2) as (
 SELECT distinct t.obj_1, t.obj_2 
   FROM temp4 t
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT c.obj_1, t.obj_2 
   FROM closure c, temp4 t 
   WHERE c.obj_2=t.obj_1)
SELECT * FROM closure
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, can't believe I forgot that, but for some reason its not an infinite loop, any suggestions how to figure this one out?

Comment: Add a stop condition in the SELECT after the UNION (within the CTE). If you cannot find any add a counter to both queries in the cte and use it in the WHERE condition to limit the loops

Comment: Could you show me an example of a stop explain or explain further? Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: Here is a good article with explanations and examples http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0307steinbach/0307steinbach.html

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it!